# Related to sign function

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was reading a research publication, where I came across the following statement:

$R[(\frac{1}{s})^{a+ib}]= (\frac{1}{s})^a(\cos(b*\ln\frac{1}{s}))$

Since cos is an even function , the sign of b is non effective. Thus, the above equation is modified to :

$R[(\frac{1}{s})^{a+ib}]= (\frac{1}{s})^a(\cos(b*\ln\frac{1}{s})^{-\text{sign(b)}})$

Please explain how is the second equation obtained from the first equation.

Comment: Which "research publication" was this?

Comment: It is a very reputed publication in  in the area of systems and control

Comment: Too "reputed" to give a reference for??

Comment: Nonlinear Dynamics, Springer

Comment: Ah! A book with a title and publisher, but no author!

Comment: New tuning design schemes of fractional complex-order PI controller., Masoomeh Shahiri · Abolfazl Ranjbar ·
Mohammad Reza Karami · Reza Ghaderi May 2016, Volume 84, Issue 3, pp 1813–1835

Comment: Notice the wording. The article is *not* saying that the second equation is obtained from the first. It is saying that the author wants an equation where the sign of $b$ has some effect on the value, so the author has modified - not derived - the original equation to include an effect for the sign of $b$. As to why the author can do this, I cannot say without reading the article, but obviously the expression is not something definitively established.